# How to Display the details of a single person from a text file onto the console in C# from a PhoneBook for example?

Tags: c#

```
            static void AddContact()
        {
            string path = @"C:\Users\...\Desktop\Projekte\C# Übungen\ContactList/contacts.txt";
            string name, address;
            int phoneNumber;

            bool addingContact = true;
            string response;
            
            List<string> ContactList = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList();

            while(addingContact)
            {
                System.Console.Write("Name: ");
                name = Console.ReadLine();
                
                System.Console.Write("Nummer: ");
                phoneNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                System.Console.Write("Adresse: ");
                address = Console.ReadLine();

                ContactList.Add($"Name: {name}");
                ContactList.Add($"Nummer: {phoneNumber}");
                ContactList.Add($"Adresse: {address} \n---------------------------------");

                foreach (var contact in ContactList)
                {
                    File.WriteAllLines(path, ContactList);
                }

                Console.Clear();

                System.Console.WriteLine("Contact added successfully! Would you like to Add another Contact? (y)(n)");
                response = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
                if(response == "y")
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                }
                else
                {
                    addingContact = false;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Good bye!");
        }

        static void ShowContact()
        {
            string path = @"C:\Users\...\Desktop\Projekte\C# Übungen\ContactList/contacts.txt";
            string response;

            System.Console.WriteLine("Would you like to see all contacts (0) or a specific one (1)?");
            response = Console.ReadLine();
            
            switch (response)
            {
                case "0":
                    File.ReadAllLines(path);
                        break;
                case "1":
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Type the name of the user: ");
                    string username = Console.ReadLine();
                    File.ReadAllLines(path)

                        break;
            }
        }
```

Thats everything. In the switch Statement at case 1 is where the problem is. I want it to look something like this if the user types John for example:

Name: John
Number: 233
Address: lolol 23
I already tried out something but i stopped in the middle of writing it because i realized that i dont actually know how to code that so i made my way over to stackoverflow to ask for help, thanks. Please be polite and i know that this code isnt the best, im a beginner.

Edit: I just found out that ShowContacts doesnt work at all

Edit 2: Fixed it with a foreach loop and List

```
            List<string> contacts = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList();

            System.Console.WriteLine("Would you like to see all contacts (0) or a specific one (1)?");
            response = Console.ReadLine();
            
            switch (response)
            {
                case "0":
                    foreach (var contact in contacts)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(contact);
                    }
                        break;
            }
```

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: So after you read the file into an array, how will you search for a specific name? Tell us the algorithm

Comment: @KarenPayne No, i decided to try out this project by myself.

Comment: @CaiusJard i dont know.

Comment: OK, so grab a pen and paper and write out the algorithm, in the language you think in (e.g. English) not C#. Here is string array `x` read from a file, it represents N people and there are N*3 entries in the array because there are 3 lines per person. What is your algorithm? Hint: use a loop over `x` to find something, then the other information you seek is near it somehow

Answer (score 0):

Save your contact to json format, like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.IO;

namespace JsonTester
{
    // Open Package Manager Console:
    //   Tools >> Nuget Package Manager >> Package Manager Console
    // 
    // Install libraries through Package Manager Console:
    // PM > Install-Package System.Text.Json -Version 6.0.1

    internal class Program
    {
        static List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();
        static readonly string MY_CONTACT = @"D:\MyContact.txt";

        class Contact {
            public string Name { get; set; }    
            public string Number { get; set; }                     
            public string Address { get; set; }    
        }

        static void EnterContact() {

            var contact = new Contact();

            Console.WriteLine("Name: ");
            contact.Name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Number: ");
            contact.Number = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Address: ");
            contact.Address = Console.ReadLine();

            contactList.Add(contact);
        }

        static void SaveContact() {
            if (contactList.Count > 0) {
                foreach (Contact contact in contactList) {
                    String strContactJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(contact);
                    File.AppendAllText(MY_CONTACT, strContactJson + "\n");
                }
            }
        }

        static void ReadContact()
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Read contact list:\n");

                String[] strContactJsonArr = File.ReadAllLines(MY_CONTACT);
                if (strContactJsonArr.Length > 0)
                {
                    foreach (String s in strContactJsonArr)
                    {
                        Contact contact = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Contact>(s);
                        if (contact != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Name:    " + contact.Name);
                            Console.WriteLine("Number:  " + contact.Number);
                            Console.WriteLine("Address: " + contact.Address);
                            Console.WriteLine("");
                        }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Found {0} contacts\n\n", strContactJsonArr.Length);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception) {
                Console.WriteLine("Contact list is empty\n");
            }
        }

        static bool SearchContact(String name)
        {
            try
            {
                String[] strContactJsonArr = File.ReadAllLines(MY_CONTACT);
                if (strContactJsonArr.Length > 0)
                {
                    foreach (String s in strContactJsonArr)
                    {
                        Contact contact = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Contact>(s);
                        if (contact != null)
                        {
                            if (contact.Name.Equals(name)) {
                                Console.WriteLine("");
                                Console.WriteLine("Name:    " + contact.Name);
                                Console.WriteLine("Number:  " + contact.Number);
                                Console.WriteLine("Address: " + contact.Address);
                                Console.WriteLine("");
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
            return false;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("- Press S for search contact.\n- Press N for new contact.\n- Press R for read contact list.\n");

                ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey(true);
                if (key.KeyChar == 's' || key.KeyChar == 'S')
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Searching contact.");
                    Console.Write("Enter name: ");
                    String name = Console.ReadLine();

                    bool isFounded = SearchContact(name);
                    if (isFounded)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Contact is found\n");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Contact isn't found!\n");
                    }
                }
                else if (key.KeyChar == 'n' || key.KeyChar == 'N')
                {
                    EnterContact();
                    SaveContact();
                }
                else if (key.KeyChar == 'r' || key.KeyChar == 'R') {
                    ReadContact();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Console Output:
[image: ![enter image description here]

MyContact.txt (contact save in JSON format):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if each item is broken down by three values consider chunking the data by three than iterate the results.

Change the Debug.WriteLine to Console.WriteLine below for your code.

Extension method for chunking

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static List<List<T>> ChunkBy<T>(this List<T> source, int chunkSize) 
        => source
            .Select((value, index) => new { Index = index, Value = value })
            .GroupBy(x => x.Index / chunkSize)
            .Select(grp => grp.Select(v => v.Value).ToList())
            .ToList();
}
```

File contents

```
John
111
John's address
Mary
222
Mary's address
Bill
333
Bill's address
```

Code to first assert data is divisible by three than read the data, no assertion of data types or if null values are performed.

```
var contents = File.ReadAllLines("TextFile1.txt");
if (contents.Length % 3 == 0)
{
    var results = contents.ToList().ChunkBy(3);

    foreach (var list in results)
    {

        Debug.WriteLine($"   Name: {list[0]}");
        Debug.WriteLine($" Number: {list[1]}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"Address: {list[2]}");

    }
}
else
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Malformed");
}
```

**Edit**: placed into a method

```
private static void ViewAllContacts()
{
    var fileName = "TextFile1.txt";
    if (File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        var contents = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
        if (contents.Length % 3 == 0)
        {
            var results = contents.ToList().ChunkBy(3);

            foreach (var list in results)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"   Name: {list[0]}");
                Debug.WriteLine($" Number: {list[1]}");
                Debug.WriteLine($"Address: {list[2]}");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Malformed");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{fileName} not found");
    }
}
```